# Graph API mutual friends request error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting error while requesting **mutual friends**:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"fields": @"context.fields(mutual_friends)",
                         };
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@", friendId]
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          if (!error) {
                          NSLog(@"MUTUALS = %@",result);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"MUTUAL ERROR %@",error);
                          }
                      }];
```

MUTUAL ERROR Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x788b68f0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api";
            type = GraphMethodException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
    }, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}

**friendId** is correct for sure. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved: user with "friendId" didn't grant corresponding permission